# Allow creating directories from applications

Tags: permissions

I just started using Ubuntu a week ago. I noticed that applications don't have permissions to create directories. E.g. I can't create a new directory from my LibreOffice Writer save as dialog.

Can I do something to change that and is it wise to do so?

Comment: Are you trying to create directories outside your user's home directory? You might not have write permissions there.

Comment: You must have write permissions over the unity that you are trying for save the file. You could have different permissions levels over different drives.

Comment: Sorry about this, I misunderstood something, I was actually able to create a folder. I'll leave the question because the answers contain some useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have default permissions to write and create folders in your home directory.  You do not have default permissions to write or create folders anywhere else.

You home folder will be found at /home/username/ and most applications like LibreOffice will default to here, or possibly /home/username/Documents

With a few exceptions it's a bad habit to get into writing elsewhere in the filesystem for just data.  These special cases are set up with special permissions and are for specific purposes - eg /media/username.

If you are having problems writing to your home directories or creating folders in them then it might indicate that there is a permissions problem which needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Any application that you start runs with exactly the same permissions as you have - so LibreOffice can create folders where you are allowed to do it.
You should keep all your own files within the tree of your home directory, that makes backups easier - there you will have full permissions to create folders, documents etc.